# Left join with count group by not displaying all left tables null records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, left-join

I have two tables Broadcastlists and Contacts(foreign key of broadcastlist). I want to show broadcastlist tables all records and count of broadcastlistid in contacts table.

My Query:-

```
SELECT b.id, count(c.broadcastlist_id)as Recepients,b.name 
from Broadcastlists b 
LEFT JOIN Contacts c ON b.id = c.broadcastlist_id 
group by c.broadcastlist_id;
```

Broadcastlists:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 |
| 2 | Test 2 |
| 3 | Test 4 |
| 4 | Test 5 |

Contacts:

| Id | Name | Broadcastlist_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul | 2 |
| 2 | Mansi | 1 |
| 3 | Nisha | 2 |
| 4 | Nidhi | 2 |
| 5 | Prashant | 1 |

I want Output like this

| Id | Name | Recepients(count) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Test 2 | 3 |
| 3 | Test 3 | 0 |
| 4 | Test 4 | 0 |

But, Output come like this, shows only one null record from left table I want all null data from left table

| Id | Name | Recepients(count) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Test 2 | 3 |
| 3 | Test 3 | 0 |

Comment: Why do you group by the same column you want to count?

Comment: Broadcastlists ID 3 & 4 have name as 'Test 4' & 'Test 5' respectively however, in your desired output the name changes to 'Test 5' & 'Test 4'. Is it just mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have grouped with a wrong column. Try this:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, COUNT(c.broadcastlist_id) AS Recepients 
FROM Broadcastlists b 
LEFT JOIN Contacts c ON b.id = c.broadcastlist_id 
GROUP BY b.id, b.name;
```

Output

| id | name | Recepients |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Test 2 | 3 |
| 3 | Test 4 | 0 |
| 4 | Test 5 | 0 |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7995f404f96875893f696518622bf019).